# PHP Print Gameserver info PNG

Tags: php

Well, I have made a simple script that prints server info into a PNG Picture, It does work but there are some few problems.

I used a free script that gets variables from a source servers using php and then prints the output, I editied it so it will print into a picture, but somehow, It wont print the players and map values.

This is the config.php that the script uses.

```
<?php

$servers = array (array ('name' => '[TF2] gameTek Idle Trade Server #1 [NO]',
                         'ip' => '84.234.160.79',
                         'port' => 27015),
                         array ('name' => '[TF2] gameTek Achevments Idle Trade Server #2 [NO]',
                         'ip' => '84.234.160.79',
                         'port' => 27017), 

                         array ('name' => '[TF2] gameTek BOT Fun #3 [NO]',
                         'ip' => '84.234.160.79',
                         'port' => 27016),
                           array ('name' => '[TF2] gameTek Achevments Idle Trade Server #5 [DFW]',
                         'ip' => '50.56.179.18',
                         'port' => 27015)
                         );
/*
$cachelifetime = 30;
$cachefile = './cache/servers.html';
*/
$output = '
<p><a href="steam://connect/#ip#:#port#">
<img 
src="Generate.php?n=#name#&p=#players#/#maxplayers#&m=#map#" alt="" /></a></p>
';

?>
```

The output when it prints is this

```
http://teamgamers.net/GetInfoServer/Generate.php?n=[TF2]%20gameTek%20Idle%20Trade%20Server%20#1 [NO]&p=3/32&m=tek_idle_trade_v5
```

So, How can I make it so it works perfectly, and not like it is now, that it only prints the server name and not the rest?
I have tried figuring out a bit, but with no luck.

Generate.php

```
<?php
$Name = $_GET['n'];
$Players = $_GET['p'];
$Map = $_GET['m'];
$Image = @ImageCreateFromPNG("./Server.png");
$Cord = imagecolorallocate($Image, 255, 255, 255);
imagestring($Image,15,60,7,$Name,14);
imagestring($Image,15,62,37,$Players,14);
imagestring($Image,15,140,37,$Map,14);
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($Image);
?>
```

Comment: The hash (`#`) is breaking your script. You have to replace it with `%23`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Check out urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php); basically, everything you put into the url needs to be passed into urlencode to make sure it doesn't contain any meta characters.

```
$servers = array (array ('name' => urlencode('[TF2] gameTek Idle Trade Server #1 [NO]'),
// and so on...
```